# Efficient way to sum an array of integers in Julia

Tags: julia

I have an 2D array which I want to modify so as to sum a given element in a row with all the elements before it, so for example, if I have an array:

```
[1 2; 3 6; 4 7; 4 8]
```

I want to be able to transform it to

```
[1 2; 4 8; 8 15; 12 23]
```

I can do so using the following snippet in julia:

```
for i in 1:10,
   for k in 2:size(d,1),
          d([k,i] += d[k-1,i)];
   end
end
```

But I assume there must be a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: If by "efficient" you mean "performance," as long as you put that loop in a function, it will basically be just as efficient as the library function---the library function differs only in generality, allowing you to pick any dimension. One of the pleasures of using Julia is that you don't have to rely on library functions for everything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there is: **cumsum**

```
julia> d = [1 2; 3 6; 4 7; 4 8]
4x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  6
 4  7
 4  8

julia> cumsum(d)
4x2 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2
  4   8
  8  15
 12  23
```

Answer (score 8):

As per @tholy's comment, the awesome thing about julia is that built-in functions aren't special and aren't magically faster than user-defined ones. They are both fast. I modified your function and I got it to perform about the same as the built-in `cumsum`:

```
function testA!(arr)
    @inbounds for i in 1:size(arr, 2)
        tmp = arr[1, i]
        for k in 2:size(arr,1)
            tmp += arr[k, i]
            arr[k,i] = tmp
        end
    end
    arr
end

function testB!(arr)
    cumsum!(arr, arr)
end
```

I constructed test arrays:

```
arr = rand(1:100, 10^5, 10^2)
arr2 = copy(arr)
```

and I got the following timings:

```
@time testA!(arr)
0.007645 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)

@time testB!(arr2)
0.007704 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

which are basically equivalent.